# ImageJ: Analyze particles in different ROI at the same time

Tags: imagej

I am measuring vessel area in different annual rings (trees; dendrochronology). I captured high quality pictures with approximatelly 20 annual rings. Each annual ring is my ROI.

I croped my image into 20 smaller images, each annual ring is one image. I open each image, I treshold it and use function: analyze particles.

However, it would be much less time consuming, if I could use my original image with 20 rings; I would separate each annual ring by defining ROI and I would label each ROI by 2012, 2011, 2010... After I would treshold the image and use function analyze particles. In my result table I would get area of vessel lumen for each vessel, separately for each annual ring.

The question is: is it possible to use ROI Manager and to set more ROIs and to analyze particles in them.

Thank you very much for your time.

Jernej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ROI Manager](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-30.html#sub%3aROI-Manager...) to store your ROIs. Then use the [ImageJ macro language](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html) and its built-in [roiManager functions](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/functions.html#roiManager) to loop over all ROIs. Record your analysis via *Plugins > Macros > Record...* to get the relevant macro commands.

Here's an example:

```
id = getImageID();
setAutoThreshold("Default");
for (i=0 ; i<roiManager("count"); i++) {
    selectImage(id);
    roiManager("select", i);
    run("Analyze Particles...", "size=0-Infinity circularity=0.00-1.00 show=Masks clear");
}
```

To answer the **additional questions** you posted in another answer:

- You get the name of the current ROI using `Roi.getName()` that you can use to name the results file:

  ```
  current = Roi.getName();
  saveAs("Results", "/path/to/results/Results_" + current + ".txt");
  ```
- Alternatively, you can include the current ROI name in each line of your results by checking *Display label* in the *Analyze > Set Measurements...* dialog, resulting in a macro command similar to this:

  ```
  run("Set Measurements...", "area display redirect=None decimal=3");
  ```

Please see the [macro language documentation](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html) and the [ImageJ mailing list archives](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html) before posting any new questions related to ImageJ macros.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Tomorrow I will bite in this macro. I believe it is very easy, but I don't have many experiences with programming. But I am sure it will work.