# Each ROI Analyze particles in separate output file; ImageJ

Tags: output, imagej, roi

Hello to all from Slovenia!

My issue: I am running particle analysis in different ROI using the following macro:

```
id = getImageID();
for (i=0 ; i<roiManager("count"); i++) {
    selectImage(id);
    roiManager("select", i);
    run("Analyze Particles...", "size=0.008-Infinity circularity=0.00-1.00 show=Outlines display");
}
```

What bothers me is that I get all results in one output file. I need each ROI in separate file (so I will be able to open it later in R). So, I would appreciate any suggestion, how can I change macro in order to get each results of ROI particle analysis in different file (Outlines and result table).

Thank you,
Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292384/imagej-analyze-particles-in-different-roi-at-the-same-time), I had edited my answer to include the following additional explanations:

- You get the name of the current ROI using `Roi.getName()` that you can use to name the results file:

  ```
  current = Roi.getName();
  saveAs("Results", "/path/to/results/Results_" + current + ".txt");
  ```
- Alternatively, you can include the current ROI name in each line of your results by checking *Display label* in the *Analyze > Set Measurements...* dialog, resulting in a macro command similar to this:

  ```
  run("Set Measurements...", "area display redirect=None decimal=3");
  ```

Please see the [macro language documentation](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html) and the [ImageJ mailing list archives](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html) before posting any new questions related to ImageJ macros.

To save the outlines, you can save the resulting image accordingly, naming it from the ROI name.